# Creating an AWS API connected to Integromat

Tags: rest, aws-api-gateway, make.com

Using the AWS API Gateway, I would like to build an API, which can only handle a `POST` request, receives an url (i.e. https://something.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/apidomain?url=google.com), forwards the url to an integromat webhook and logs a "success"-`json` to the user.

Any advice on how to start without building complicated Lambda functions?

Comment: The above description fits a simple Lambda function definition. No need to build a complicated one. ;-)

Comment: Can you give me an indication on how it might look like? I am very new and inexperienced in this field 